# echo images using php

Tags: php, mysql

what am i trying to do is echo an image using php,
my code is really simple..

i have stored the path of the image in mysql db..
the path of the image is: `../users/profiles/23/images/dps/1409947526.jpg`

now i am using the following code to output this picture:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("error!");
mysql_select_db("xone");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdpcover WHERE id='23'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$dir = $result['dp_address'];
$dp_name = $result['dp_name'];
$dp = $dir.$dp_name;
echo $dp;
echo "<img src='$dp' />";
```

but when i run this code, all i get is an broken image!

thanks in advance!

Comment: you might have missed '/ ' there .
 try $dp = $dir.'/'.$dp_name

Comment: Whats the output of echo $dp; in your code?

Comment: Look at the HTML you are generating, not the PHP source code. Look at the URL you are setting the src attribute to. Compare that to the actual URL of the image.

Comment: Is the path the reachable by your webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please try this and please check your image path url correct....
<?php
  //here your code
?>//close php  tag  and try this ...  
<img src="<?php echo $dp; ?>"/>
<?php

//your code here

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
    echo "<img src='".$dp."' />";
```

Answer (score -1):

View the source of the output HTML. This will tell you the image path. You probably need to modify it.

Also, remember to set your base URL in a PHP config file to avoid repeating URL paths.

Comment: this is the output source of the htm; : <img src='../users/profiles/23/images/dps/1409947526.jpg' />

Comment: i have tried to open the image but it doesnot opens

Comment: http://localhost/xone/users/profiles/23/images/dps/1409947526.jpg

this is the path when i opens the image in new tab, but it still not worked, and the image do exists in the directory!